# Converting a recursive algorithm to a runtime function

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion

```
void Sort(int A[], int left, int right)
{
    int p;

    if (left < right)
    {
        p = (right + left + 2)/3;

        Sort(A, left, left+p-1);
        Sort(A, left+p, left+2*p-1);

        MergeSort(A, left+2*p, right);

        Merge3(A, left, left+p, left+2*p, right);
    }
}
```

I need to convert this function into a mathematical expression in order to solve it's run-time complexity.

I know  that `MergeSort()`'s complexity is of $\Theta(n \log n)$ and that `Merge3()`'s complexity is of $\Theta(n)$.

I can't figure how to transform this into a recursive mathematical expression.

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709106/time-complexity-of-a-recursive-algorithm

Comment: @G.Bach, I tried writing it down on a paper for small n's but it didn't get me anywhere

Comment: What did you write down, where did it go wrong?

Comment: It went wrong in `Sort` functions, the p confuses me very much. I don't understand the logic of summing right left and two an then dividing it by 3.

Comment: Do you understand that for the purpose of $\Theta$-analysis, most individual lines can be compacted to cost $1$?

Comment: Yes @Raphael, I do understand it. I have analysed some simpler functions in the near past but this function is a harder to understand and analyse.

Comment: @Quaker I suggest you translate the algorithm line by line and show us your result. Then we can figure out where your problem lies.

Comment: Translate to what @Raphael? I really am not interested in the explicit answer.

Comment: @Quaker A function $T(n)$ that maps input size $n$ to (an approximation of) the number of elementary operations executed (in the worst case).

Comment: @Raphael, $T(n) = \Theta(1) + 2T(X) + \Theta(nlogn)$ my problem is figuring the recursion itself which I marked as $X$, I guess it should relay on the `left` `right` and `p` but I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind the calculation of `p` thus I can't seems to find out what's $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use `right - left` as $n$ for the parameter of the runtime recursion. What is the size of the subparts?

Closer hint:

> Note that the algorithm separates the input part of the array in three approximately equal-sized parts; the first two are sorted recursively, the third with Mergesort. This should be reflected in your recurrence.

Almost finished:

> Assuming `Merge3` runs in time $\Theta(n)$ und `MergeSort` in time $\Theta(n \log n)$, you get a recurrence of the form
>
>  $\qquad\displaystyle T(n) \approx 2T(n/3) + \Theta(n) + \Theta(n/3 \log(n/3))$
>
>  since all parts have size $\approx p \approx n/3$. Solve this with the Master theorem and flesh out the details.

Comment: Master Theorem actually solves this like a magic but I need to solve it by using the recurrence on itself until I find a pattern which is insanely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Usual merge sort takes a list of size $n$, divides it into two halves, sorts the two halves recursively, then merges them in $O(n)$. Your routine take a list of size $n$, divides it into *three thirds*, sorts the first two recursively and the last one using mergesort (this detail is a bit strange; you'd expect all three parts to be sorted recursively), then merges them in $O(n)$.